# What is the difference between TIN vs MESH vs TERRAIN in the context of GIS?

Tags: terrain, tin, mesh

I couldn't seem to fully understand the differences between TIN, MESH, and TERRAIN dataset formats in GIS.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulated_irregular_network)

> a triangulated irregular network (TIN)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulated_irregular_network) is a representation of a
> continuous surface consisting entirely of triangular facets (a
> triangle mesh)

and [QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_mesh/mesh_properties.html#what-s-a-mesh)

[image]

it seems like TIN is a subset of Mesh (Triangular Mesh to be exact). Is TIN a subset of mesh?

Then there is this Terrain data format by ESRI, which seems like something only relevant in ESRI vs a general GIS concept.
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/terrains/terrain-dataset-concepts.htm

What is the difference between these three GIS datasets formats?

Answer (score 2):

Good Question - perhaps to add to the confusion, its possible that there are two different aspects to this - The 'Theoretical answer' - and the 'software specific' answers.
I will also just edit your last comment, **"What is the difference between these 3 GIS datasets formats?"** - I wouldn't call them dataset formats, but rather, these 3 concepts.

Tin, Mesh, Terrain.

The QGIS documentation - in my opinion has some really good conceptual and non-software specific definitions, so credit given to those doc's.

Mesh - "A mesh is an unstructured grid usually with temporal and other components. The spatial component contains a collection of vertices, edges and/or faces, in 2D or 3D space"

TIN - It then goes onto say:
"2D meshes: consist of faces with triangles, regular or unstructured quads." - So I am thinking that this answers your question about whether TIN is a subset of a Mesh. Yes. Mesh's can also be quads or mixed even. A TIN is a triangular implementation of a mesh. TINs can be generated in different software, using different tools and have different end-implementations, so would be considered a concept.

The Terrain Dataset itself is a proprietary implementation of a TIN. (Again, ESRI documentation is helpful here). This would be the only concept that I would call a 'dataset'. From their website -

*"A terrain dataset is a multiresolution, TIN-based surface built from measurements stored as features in a geodatabase. They're typically made from lidar, sonar, and photogrammetric sources. Terrains reside in the geodatabase, inside feature datasets with the features used to construct them."*

Comment: Thanks. So it seems that Terrain is not a general GIS thing then, it is just some specific ESRI thing?

Comment: yes I would say that given that they are structured inside an ESRI proprietary file format (ESRI Geodatabase) they are specific to ESRI. It might be that other software can export to this format or read this format, but I have no knowledge of that.

Comment: QGIS is able to read ESRI Terrain, at least TIN Terrain.